# Google Sheet query where B = X only if B is not empty

Tags: sql, google-sheets

I would like to make a query to filter some information in my table depending on different fields I can choose from a drop down. (D1, D2, D3, D4).

This query below works, but only if I specify 4 criteria.
I would like to have a query only on D1 and D2 criteria if I leave D3 and D4 empty.

```
=QUERY(Data!A2:S; 
"select * 
where B = '"&D1&"'    >> only if D1 not empty
and C = '"&D2&"'      >> only if D2 not empty
and G = '"&D3&"'      >> only if D3 not empty
and I = '"&D4&"'      >> only if D4 not empty
" )
```

Comment: Don't put "solved" in the title - accept the answer that solved your problem.

Comment: Where "accept" means "click the checkmark to the left of an answer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ignore a condition when the relevant input cell is empty, use a conditional statement that will replace its content by the column letter in comparison:

```
= QUERY(Data!A2:S;
  "select * 
  where B = "  & if(len(D1), "'"&D1&"'", "B") 
  & " and C = " & if(len(D2), "'"&D2&"'", "C")  
  & " and G = " & if(len(D3), "'"&D3&"'", "G")  
  & " and I = " & if(len(D4), "'"&D4&"'", "I")  
  )
```

This way, if D1 is empty, the comparison becomes "... where B = B and ..."

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems to be what I'm looking for, but when I try your formula, I get "Error". Is there anything wrong ? =QUERY(Data!A2:S; "select * where B = '" & if(len(D1), D1, "B") & "' )")

Comment: There is never just an "error", errors come with an explanation... In this case, you have & "' )" in the query string, which should not be there. General advice: when forming a query string by complex concatenation, try it without the "query" part: just form the string with `= " select * where B = '" & ` and so on. Read it to see if it makes sense.

Comment: Here is the link of an example file : [>link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ptLJQmsPHfVkvbT4c3VaQw5pl_EwgC6kvWab6ChIiIY/edit#gid=1662676128)

Comment: Okay, besides the extra ) there was an issue with the placement of single quotes. I edited the answer so it has the complete query command.

Comment: Great !! Thanks a lot ! It's really a big help for me ! Have a great day ;-)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(Data!A2:S; 
"select * 
where B = '"&IF(D1="","noSuchWordThere", D1)&"'    >> only if D1 not empty
and C = '"&IF(D2="","noSuchWordThere", D2)&"'      >> only if D2 not empty
and G = '"&IF(D3="","noSuchWordThere", D3)&"'      >> only if D3 not empty
and I = '"&IF(D4="","noSuchWordThere", D4)&"'      >> only if D4 not empty
" )
```

Comment: This is not what the OP wants. If D3 is empty, he wants the query to select based on the cells D1,D2,D4. In your case, the query will return nothing.